# Llamar metodo a User Control desde Parent Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Necesito llamar un metodo en un User Control (.ascx) desde su Parent Page (Web Form) usando javascript.

Probe con lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
function llamarMetodo(){
var resultado = <%=userControl.MetodoEnUserControl()%>;}
```

Comment: Pero cuando usas `<%=` eso es codigo servidor no cliente, esa parte no es javascript

Comment: Indica por favor, el código completo del método y del javascript.